# How to split unit strings consistently using NLP in PHP?

Tags: php, nlp

Given the ingredients;

- 1 tbsp olive oil
- 4 rashers smoked streaky bacon, finely chopped
- 2 medium onions, finely chopped
- 500g beef mince

I want to be able to consistently split them, to save the unit, ingredient, and preparation separately. E.g

```
[
    [
        "qty" => "1", 
        "unit" => "tbsp",
        "ingredient" => "olive oil",
        "preparation" => null,
    ],
    [
        "qty" => "4", 
        "unit" => "rashers",
        "ingredient" => "smoked streaky bacon",
        "preparation" => "finely chopped",
    ],
    [
        "qty" => "2", 
        "unit" => "medium",
        "ingredient" => "onions",
        "preparation" => "finely chopped",
    ],
    [
        "qty" => "500", 
        "unit" => "g",
        "ingredient" => "beef mince",
        "preparation" => null,
    ],
]
```

I originally thought regex would be enough, but I quickly realised not all sites format ingredients in the same way, so my patterns started to get out of control.

So I decided using some sort of NLP and training some type of model would probably be the best approach. However, I'm pretty out of my depth with NLP and I've been unable to find much info about how to use NLP to achieve something like this, so I'm not really sure what part of NLP I should be focusing on in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

For two years I worked on pretty much this topic at a start-up dedicated to processing recipe data sourced from food websites.

It is not a trivial problem.

The approach we followed was to have a long list of ingredients, modifiers, measurements, etc, and then use a parser with a context-free grammar to analyse the input.

Lists of ingredients are not written for computers, so you will find a lot of variation ("*500g of the freshest sole you get get at your local fishmonger - there's a good one in Hampton Rd.*"). There will be multiple measurements ("*2 medium (50g) onions*"), and lots of other items you won't expect.

The simplest way might be to just try and do a string match on the lines, but don't get your hopes up that you will be able to get it right all the time. If you want to do it 'properly', prepare for a big project.